# remove parts of string with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, string

I have somewhat of an odd situation, where I need to fix a bug in a website where, when a string is created (dynamically) it adds 5 spaces before the string and 5 spaces after the string. Obviously, the best thing to do would be to fix the back end code and get rid of those spaces... long story short, I can't and I have to do it with javascript. I'm not quite sure how to do it, but this is what I was thinking

```
<!--Dynamically generated string including spaces added in backend-->
<span id="balance">     245.34     </span>
```

My idea was to do the following with javascript

```
function removespace()
{
  var oldString = document.getElementById('balance');
  var newString = (THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK... I NEED TO REMOVE THE SPACES);
  document.getElementByID('balance').innerHTML = newString;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks!

ALSO FORGOT TO MENTION: I can't use any javascript libraries like prototype or jquery.

Edit: I have this so far... but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<span id="balance">     $245.00     </span>

 <script>
 function removespace()
 {
   var oldString = document.getElementById('balance');
   var newString = oldString.trim ();
   document.getElementByID('balance').innerHTML = newString;
 }

 String.prototype.trim = function() {
 return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
 }
 </script>
```

here is the solution I used... I finished it before I saw the other updates... but everyone was very helpful

```
function trim(stringToTrim) {
return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
 }
 var oldString = document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML;
 var newString = trim(oldString);
 document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = newString;
```

Comment: Why do you have to remove the spaces? HTML compress continuous spaces to one. So the rendered HTML page should only show one space before and after the value (but ok, this might still be undesirable).

Comment: Because even if it shows 1 space before or after it breaks the design of the page

Comment: Ok. I assumed it but I wanted to verify... sometimes people make a problem although they don't have any ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunetly JavaScript does not have a `trim()` function. But you can roll your own:

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
```

and then do:

```
var newString = oldString.trim ();
```

the above function is from [this website](http://www.somacon.com/p355.php) (first result on google for "javascript trim")

edit (based on your update to your question and comments):

change

```
var oldString = document.getElementById('balance');
```

to

```
var oldString = document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML;
```

and change

```
document.getElementByID('balance').innerHTML = newString;
```

to

```
document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = newString; // notice the lower case d
```

and you have to call the `removespace` function at some point (but I'm sure you already do that) :)

Comment: This is what I was just going to link to, so +1 :).  If the OP is using a framework or toolkit, look in their APIs for a trim() method so you don't duplicate code!

Comment: This is plain vanilla JavaScript code. No library required (don't let the `prototype` confuse you, it's just a JavaScript feature trough which you can extend existing classes).

Comment: I made an edit... it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure if I implemented the first part right

Answer (score 0):

Writting out of my head here.

```
var elem = doc.getElementById('balance');
var oldString = elem.innerHTML;
elem.innerHTML=oldString.(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"")
```

Something like that?

Edit: yep, only my first space is deleted, so I stole the whitespace from the answer number 1 :)

Comment: That will remove all whitespace, not just trailing/leading whitespace. Might not be a problem in his case though.

Comment: This will only remove the first occurrence  of a space.

Comment: You're right, Jan, I was writting off the top of my head, didn't think first :)

Answer (score 0):

You try something like this

```
str.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/, "").replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, "");
```

Answer (score -1):

use trim() to remove all white spaces

var newString  = oldString.trim();

or use replace to replace white spaces with empty string:

var newString  = oldString.replace(" ","");

Comment: JavaScript does not have a `trim` function. Your second solution will only replace the first occurrence of a space.

Comment: var newString = oldString.replace(/ /g,""); // g(lobal) = replace all occurences

Comment: @Jan Hančič: I have not so much insight in which browser implements which version of JavaScript or ECMAScript, but `trim()` [seems to be part of JavaScript 1.8.1 (or ECMAScript 5)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Answer (score -1):

with jQuery it's simple:

```
var newStr = jQuery.trim(oldStr);
```

Comment: he did not ask for a jQuery solution

Comment: he didn't specify that he doesn't want to use jquery and jquery is also javascript.

Answer (score -1):

If balance is  meant to be a double you could convert it to a string:

```
var c = '1234';
d = c * 1;
```

then back to a string if need be by:

```
d = c.toString();
```